# Writing a batch program for renaming files

Tags: batch-file, executable, renaming

Gentlemen and -women, one question regarding programming:

I need to write a program to batch rename files, under the following conditions:

1. All files are in a directory. Can be the same directory as the executable, if this simplifies things pathwise.
2. All files are .pdf, but this should not matter I believe.
3. All files are start with double digit prefix ranging from 01 til 99
   e.g.: 01_FileNameOriginal1.pdf ; 02_FileNameOriginal2.pdf
   This double digit needs to stay.
4. All names must be modified to a predefined range of filenames (sort of a database)  which can be embedded in the executable, or read out from an external file (being .txt, .csv, whatever is most feasible). 
   e.g.: 01_NewName1.pdf ; 02_NewName2.pdf ; ...
5. Some original filenames contain an expiry date, which is labelled "EXP YYYY MMM DD", and should be appended to the new name in a different format: "e_YYYY_MM_DD". So basically it needs to be able to use a "for" statement (to loop for the number of files), and "if" statement to search for the "EXP" (matching case), cut the string and append in the rearranged format before the file extension.
6. The result of the program can be either renaming, or returning a renamed copy. The former seems easier to do.

So to summarize: 
step 1: Run program
step 2: integer = number of files
step 3: loop: 
 3.A check first two digits, copy to a temp string. 
 3.B compare the temp string with an array of predefined filenames. The array can be embedded in the code, or read externally. For the user friendliness sake, an external read from a .csv seems easier to modify the filenames later on. 
 3.C to rename or not to rename. In case of a match:

- Assume the old file has the following name: 01_FileNameOriginal EXP YYYY MM DD Excessivetext.pdf
- Copy first two digits to a temp2 string
- Scan the old name for EXP (for length of filename, if = "EXP ", matching case) and cut the following 10 characters. Put YYYY, MM, and DD in seperate strings. All essential value has now been extracted from the old filename.
- Match dbl digits with the first two digits of filenames in the database. Copy the new name to a temp string.
- Rename the file with the new name: eg 01_NewName.pdf
- Append date strings before the extension: eg 01_NewName_e_YYYY_MM_DD.pdf
- Note: date can be extracted in a single string, as long as spaces are replaced by underscores. Probably shorter to program.

in case of no match: copy old filename, and put it in a temp string, to return at the end of the process as an error (or .txt) file, with filenames that could not be renamed. 
step 4: finish and return error or report (see previous)

Question: 
Based on these conditions, what would be the easiest way to get started? Are there freeware programs that can do such a thing. If not what is the best approach. I have basic programming knowledge (Java/VBA), some small C++ stints but nothing spectacular. I have only programmed in a programming environment and have never produced any executables or batch files or the likes so I don't have any idea how to start atm, but wouldn't mind to give it a shot. As long as it's a guided shot, and not one in the dark cos that's where I am now.

Would love to hear some thoughts on this.

Greetings

Wouter

Comment: You could probably get that easily done in any of those languages since you have quite a few rules that require parsing of the file name.

Comment: then how precisely do I turn that into a batch .exe file? 
I heard Python could do the trick, but I have no experience with this language, so I would need quite the resources to get me started. 

The program, in the end, needs to run on any type of windows OS, regardless of software that's installed. So I don't want it based in excel, or requiring any third party software/freeware/... 

Does this change the way you would tackle the problem?

Comment: You could write it in a compiled language such as C or C++. After writing the program, you would compile it so that it is in an executable. Alternatively, if Java is installed, you could write it in Java and create an executable JAR file. Although in way, you could say Java is a third party software and thus the former is a better option.

Comment: Consider easier languages like Ruby or Python.